# Primefaces fileupload filter when web.xml not used

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, jboss7.x, servlet-filters

I want to use the primefaces fileupload control in my jboss 7 web application. As I don't use any web.xml (not required with Java EE 6), how can I specify the filter required to make the fileupload work properly? Should I create a web.xml for that or can I use annotations instead?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you should indeed be creating a `web.xml` file yourself. It's not that hard, just create a file in `/WEB-INF/web.xml` with the following kickoff template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <!-- Your config here. -->

</web-app>
```

If you've really a hard head in and have some big aversion against "XML boilerplate", then you could always homebrew a filter class which extends the PrimeFaces file upload filter with the desired `@WebFilter` annotation.

```
package com.example;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter;

@WebFilter("*.jsf") // Or @WebFilter(servletNames={"Faces Servlet"})
public class AnnotatedPrimeFacesFileUploadFilter extends FileUploadFilter {
    // NOOP.
}
```

Comment: I guess the argument I can come up with, to use the annotation approach is avoid configuration of a lot of different things in a central place (file).

Comment: @Aksel: Filters can't be ordered by annotations. So if you need to invoke filters in a certian order, you should still need to resort to "good 'ol" `web.xml`.

Comment: Thanks, that is a useful restriction to be aware of. I was just about to move them to annotations. Will think twice then atleast

Comment: Thanks a lot BalusC, I have indeed used a web.xml in case I need to use several filters in the future.

Comment: Please note that in my case, the filter configuration proposed by the PrimeFaces User's Guide 3.4 did not work. I had to replace `<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>` by `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`. Could anyone explain why I needed to make this modification? Thanks

Comment: @vcattin: either the `<servlet-name>` of your `javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet` configuration is not the same, or you're using an URL rewrite library like PrettyFaces.